# How to set large icon on WinForms application

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 icon sizing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042158/windows-7-icon-sizing-problems)

I have ico file with the following images up to 128x128 inside. I can see that icon contains that size both in any icon editor and windows explorer. When I attach this icon to my windows forms application I can see that it doesn't use icons more then 48x48. What's the problem? Isn't it possible to set large icons for WinForms application?

Thanks.

Comment: Where don't you see the larger size?

Comment: In explorer. When I change explorer view to show large or extra large icons I still see my application with 48x48 icon.

Comment: Thanks! That's it, the problem is with the icon itself, I understood it yesterday when I tried another one, but wasn't able to understand what's the problem. Yes, that's duplicate.